# how to make canvas draw smooth curve following your finger in android studio

Tags: android-studio, canvas, path, curve, smoothing

I initially wrote my code using the

onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
....
float Xposition= event.getX();
.....
path.lineTo(Xpositon,Yposition);//simply taking the current pointer location from getX() and getY()
}

this leaves with sharp edges when you your finger fast across the screen. that point to concider here is that when you use getX() and getY() it will return only the most appropiate value of x location at the instent when that command is getting executed, some points are missed in between( if you want to test it yourself, open developer options in your mobile and turn the pointer location on and try to draw fast with your fingers in the app, you can see the diflection clearly that a lot of points shown in red by the pointer location are not taken by your app while drawing.)

Solution:
assume now time is t1
when getX() is executed

the next time when it getX() is executed the time be t2

the points missed between t1 and t2 are actually stored in getHistoricalX(int,int) // to konw how to use this please refer this under batching section you can find it :https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent

use it for rest of the points
means first take getX() of t1, then historical points and then getX() of t2

this will mostly solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ .... float Xposition= event.getX(); ..... path.lineTo(Xpositon,Yposition);//simply taking the current pointer location from getX() and getY() }

this leaves with sharp edges when you your finger fast across the screen. that point to concider here is that when you use getX() and getY() it will return only the most appropiate value of x location at the instent when that command is getting executed, some points are missed in between( if you want to test it yourself, open developer options in your mobile and turn the pointer location on and try to draw fast with your fingers in the app, you can see the diflection clearly that a lot of points shown in red by the pointer location are not taken by your app while drawing.)

Solution: assume now time is t1 when getX() is executed

the next time when it getX() is executed the time be t2

the points missed between t1 and t2 are actually stored in getHistoricalX(int,int) // to konw how to use this please refer this under batching section you can find it :https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent

use it for rest of the points means first take getX() of t1, then historical points and then getX() of t2

this will mostly solve the problem.